# Default or editable link target in editor

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

Is there any way you can specify the target of a link (to _blank forinstance) in the editor on this site?  Or could we maybe have all embedded links opening in a new window?

I have got in the habit of holding down control for all links on this site, but it's very annoying when I forget.

Answer (score 4):

This request has [come](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35677/have-all-links-open-in-a-new-tab) up [repeatedly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/make-links-posted-by-users-open-in-a-new-window) and has been/will be

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

As a workaround, consider using this [User Script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/59563)